# Alter search query condition for dataset in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-search

I am very new to Drupal and attempting to build a module that will allow admins to tag nodes with keywords to boost nodes to the top of the search results.

I have a separate DB table for the keywords and respective node IDs. This table is UNIONed with the search_index table via [hook_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/7)...

```
function mos_search_result_forcer_query_alter(QueryAlterableInterface &$query) {
    if (get_class($query) !== 'PagerDefault') { //<< check this because this function will mod all queries elsewise
        return;
    }

    // create unioned search index result set...
    $index = db_select('search_index', 's');

    $index->addField('s', 'sid');
    $index->addField('s', 'word');
    $index->addField('s', 'score');
    $index->addField('s', 'type');

    $msrfi = db_select('mos_search_result_forcer', 'm');

    $msrfi->addField('m', 'nid', 'sid');
    $msrfi->addField('m', 'keyword', 'word');
    $msrfi->addExpression('(SELECT MAX(score) + m.id / (SELECT MAX(id) FROM {mos_search_result_forcer}) FROM {search_index})', 'score');
    $msrfi->addExpression(':type', 'type', array(':type' => 'node'));

    $index->union($msrfi);

    $tables =& $query->getTables();

    $tables['i']['table'] = $index;

    return $query;
}
```

Drupal then generates the *almost* correct query...

```
SELECT 
    i.type AS type, i.sid AS sid, SUM(CAST('10' AS DECIMAL) * COALESCE(( (12.048628015788 * i.score * t.count)), 0) / CAST('10' AS DECIMAL)) AS calculated_score 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        s.sid AS sid, s.word AS word, s.score AS score, s.type AS type 
    FROM 
        search_index s 
    UNION SELECT 
        m.nid AS sid, m.keyword AS word, (
            SELECT 
                MAX(score) + m.id / (SELECT MAX(id) FROM mos_search_result_forcer) 
            FROM 
                search_index
        ) AS score, 'node' AS type 
    FROM 
        mos_search_result_forcer m
) i 
INNER JOIN node n ON n.nid = i.sid 
INNER JOIN search_total t ON i.word = t.word 
INNER JOIN search_dataset d ON i.sid = d.sid AND i.type = d.type 
WHERE (n.status = '1') 
AND( (i.word = 'turtles') )
AND (i.type = 'node') 

/* this is the problem line... */
AND( (d.data LIKE '% turtles %' ESCAPE '\\') )
/* ...end problem line */

GROUP BY i.type, i.sid 
HAVING (COUNT(*) >= '1') 
ORDER BY calculated_score DESC 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

...I need that "problem line" to read...

```
AND( (d.data LIKE '% turtles %' ESCAPE '\\') OR (d.sid IN (SELECT nid FROM mos_search_result_forcer)) )
```

...what hook can I use to add that OR condition?

- I don't want to hack Drupal's core.
- I don't want to change the union/subqueries (not my decision).
- I will optimize queries later - functionality is more important.

Thanks, smart people!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some helpful suggestions from @Clive with `hook_module_implements_alter`, and a lot of trial and error, I have finally solved this issue.

Here is the final code...

```
function mos_search_result_forcer_module_implements_alter(&$imps, $hook) {
    if ($hook !== 'query_alter' || !array_key_exists('mos_search_result_forcer', $imps)) {
        return;
    }

    $imp = $imps['mos_search_result_forcer'];

    unset($imps['mos_search_result_forcer']);

    $imps['mos_search_result_forcer'] = $imp;
}

function mos_search_result_forcer_query_alter(QueryAlterableInterface &$query) {
    if (get_class($query) !== 'PagerDefault') { //<< check this because this function will mod all queries elsewise
        return;
    }

    // create unioned search index result set...
    $index = db_select('search_index', 's');

    $index->addField('s', 'sid');
    $index->addField('s', 'word');
    $index->addField('s', 'score');
    $index->addField('s', 'type');

    $msrfi = db_select('mos_search_result_forcer', 'm');

    $msrfi->addField('m', 'nid', 'sid');
    $msrfi->addField('m', 'keyword', 'word');
    $msrfi->addExpression('(SELECT MAX(score) + m.id / (SELECT MAX(id) FROM {mos_search_result_forcer}) FROM {search_index})', 'score');
    $msrfi->addExpression(':type', 'type', array(':type' => 'node'));

    $index->union($msrfi);

    $tables =& $query->getTables();

    $tables['i']['table'] = $index;

    // needs special "or" condition to keep from filtering out forced resutls...
    class MSRFPagerDefaultHelper extends PagerDefault { //<< override to gain access to protected props
        static function msrfHelp(PagerDefault &$pagerDefault) {
            $searchQuery =& $pagerDefault->query;

            MSRFSearchQueryHelper::msrfHelp($searchQuery);
        }
    }

    class MSRFSearchQueryHelper extends SearchQuery { //<< override to gain access to protected props
        static function msrfHelp(SearchQuery &$searchQuery) {
            $conditions =& $searchQuery->conditions;

            $condition = db_or()->condition($conditions)->condition('d.sid', db_select('mos_search_result_forcer')->fields('mos_search_result_forcer', array('nid')), 'IN');

            $searchQuery->conditions = $condition;
        }
    }

    MSRFPagerDefaultHelper::msrfHelp($query);

    return $query; //<< i don't think this is needed as var is reffed - just for good measure, i guess
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic principle is to grab the [conditions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!query.inc/function/QueryConditionInterface%3A%3Aconditions/7) array, loop through and find the index for the problem condition, remove it, then re-add an identical condition along with the new one as part of a [`db_or()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_or/7)

This is un-tested and most likely won't work verbatim, but it should give you a starting point:

```
$conditions =& $query->conditions();
$index = FALSE;
$removed_condition = NULL;

for ($i = 0, $l < count($conditions); $i < $l; $i++) {
  if ($conditions[$i]['field'] == 'd.data' && $conditions[$i]['operator'] == 'LIKE') {
    $index = $i;
    $removed_condition = $condition;

    break;
  }
}

if ($index !== FALSE) {
  unset($conditions[$index]);

  $sub_query = db_select('mos_search_result_forcer')->fields('mos_search_result_forcer', array('nid'));
  $new_condition = db_or()
    ->condition('d.data', $removed_condition['value'], 'LIKE')
    ->condition('d.sid', $sub_query, 'IN');

  $query->condition($new_condition);
}
```

Comment: thank you! That code is actually very similar to the code I was experimenting with; however, the issue is that the condition I need to modified is added to the query object *after* hook_query_alter is called.  I was hoping there might be another hook that is called right before the query's execute method is called, or a hook that is called right before the query object adds conditions to itself?

Comment: It's pretty unlikely (impossible actually I think) that the query gets altered after `hook_query_alter()`...what's probably happening is another module also implements `hook_query_alter()`, and its implementation is just running after yours. You can get around that by implementing [`hook_module_implements_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7) and moving your module's `hook_query_alter()` hook to the end of the list

Comment: Thank you, again! I am able to see the condition when var_dumping the query object. The query arg (passed to `hook_query_alter`) is of type `PagerDefault`, which has a protected property `$query` of type `SearchQuery`. The protected `SearchQuery` property has the condition array I need to modify. Is there a way I can modify conditions of a nested query like that?

Comment: Interesting @chaseisabelle, never actually tried that before. I can't see anything exposed on `PagerDefault` that would get you access to the underlying query. I think extending that class like you've done is the right way to go. As an aside, it would be great if you could take the solution out of the question and put it in an answer (answering your own question is fine, encouraged even). That way people won't miss it. If you do that let me know so I can delete this answer afterwards

Comment: Thanks, @Clive. Your suggestion with `hook_module_implements_alter` was a huge help! Added my solution as an answer.